# get User ID in a Thymeleaf template

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security, thymeleaf

I have defined a URL in a Thymeleaf template to connect to a RESTful API where the logged userId is required, I've tried this but checking the source code of the template, the userId is not replaced

```
var ajaxUrl = /*[[@{/api/users/@{|~/${#authentication.id}/menus/datatableList}]]*/ "";
```

Comment: It should be inside `<script th:inline="javascript">` AFAIR..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your url expression should look like this (what you have doesn't make sense... mismatched brackets and expressions in expressions).

```
var ajaxUrl = /*[[@{/api/users/{user}/menus/datatableList(user=${#authentication.id})}]]*/ "";
```

Also, I'm not even sure that `#authentication.id` is a valid use of `#authentication`.  Have you verified that it actually contains the id and isn't resolving to null?

Comment: I got it from: ${#authentication.principal.id}